# Azure B2C Datepicker (Calendar)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm creating a custom policy that must do the following:
 1. If the user clicks to Sign up, show a screen with three input fields that are:
 a. A key (string)
 b. date of birth (I would like to display a calendar)
 c. another key (string)

However, after reading all the documentation [Add claims and customize user input using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-configure-user-input) and searching in Google, I couldn't find a way to create a "Datepicker" input field in Azure B2C.

How can I accomplish that?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
<ClaimType Id="dateOfBirth">
  <DisplayName>Date of Birth</DisplayName>
  <DataType>date</DataType>
  <AdminHelpText>The user's date of birth.</AdminHelpText>
  <UserHelpText>Your date of birth.</UserHelpText>
  <UserInputType>DateTimeDropdown</UserInputType>
  <PredicateValidationReference Id="CustomDateRange" />
</ClaimType>
```

Use DateTimeDropdown.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @Jonny answer, you canconfigure the custom data range validation like so:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimType Id="dateOfBirth">
      <DisplayName>Date of Birth</DisplayName>
      <DataType>date</DataType>
      <AdminHelpText>The user's date of birth.</AdminHelpText>
      <UserHelpText>Your date of birth.</UserHelpText>
      <UserInputType>DateTimeDropdown</UserInputType>
      <PredicateValidationReference Id="CustomDateRange" />
    </ClaimType>

    <Predicates>
      <Predicate Id="DateRange" Method="IsDateRange" HelpText="The date must be between 01-01-1980 and today.">
        <Parameters>
          <Parameter Id="Minimum">1980-01-01</Parameter>
          <Parameter Id="Maximum">Today</Parameter>
        </Parameters>
      </Predicate>
    </Predicates>

    <PredicateValidations>
      <PredicateValidation Id="CustomDateRange">
        <PredicateGroups>
          <PredicateGroup Id="DateRangeGroup">
            <PredicateReferences>
              <PredicateReference Id="DateRange" />
            </PredicateReferences>
          </PredicateGroup>
        </PredicateGroups>
      </PredicateValidation>
    </PredicateValidations>
  </ClaimsSchema>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

**Helpful links:**

- [BuildingBlocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/buildingblocks)
- [Predicates and PredicateValidations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/predicates#predicates)